# Add enter after each tag with emmet in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, emmet

I'm using WebStorm with education purposes. I have used Vim, SublimeText and Brackets with emmet plugin and when I expand an expression it is automatically formatted. For example, if I write:

```
nav>ul>li*2>a.item>img.ico+p.txt
```

I get:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="item">
            <img src="" alt="" class="ico">
            <p class="txt"></p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="item">
            <img src="" alt="" class="ico">
            <p class="txt"></p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

But in WebStorm I get:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="item"><img src="" alt="" class="ico">
        <p class="txt"></p>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="item"><img src="" alt="" class="ico">
        <p class="txt"></p>
    </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Exists a configuration that I can do to get a formated code expanding an expression with emmet in WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the Code Style settings in `Settings / Editor / Code Style / HTML`.

In your case you would exclude `a` and `img` from `Other / Inline elements`, so they get a new line.